# Make sliding text disappear as it reaches bottom of div

Tags: javascript, html, css, collision, detection

I have a div with id="text" that I am adding text to:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('text');
var p1 = document.createElement('p');
p1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text to be inputted.'));
el.insertBefore(p1, el.childNodes[0] || null);
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

After inputting multiple lines of text, I want the older text at the bottom of the div to disappear.

Can I do this using a max number in the el.childNodes[] array?
Or will I have to use collision detection as the text reaches the bottom of the div?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as `After inputting multiple lines of text` is very ambiguous, there is no way of answering it definitively. However, if you intend to insert each line as its own paragraph (or any other kind of DOM node), then you could hide the "overflowing" nodes using CSS like this: (the demo is creating 10 elements but only showing 5)

```js
const el = document.getElementById('text');
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const p1 = document.createElement('p');
  p1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text to be inputted.'));
  el.insertBefore(p1, el.childNodes[0] || null);
}
```

```css
#text > p:nth-child(n + 6) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```